# To what extent does AFQT correlate with IQ?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, measurement, test, iq, military-psychology

Wikipedia has a pretty non-informative page as to the nature of the (US) [Armed Forces Qualification Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armed_Services_Vocational_Aptitude_Battery#Armed_Forces_Qualification_Test) (AFQT) as it mostly talks of results ranges etc. What I could descipher from there is it that it has three (or maybe four, depending on how one counts) [sub]parts,

- Arithmetic Reasoning (AR) – 30 questions in 36 minutes
- Mathematics Knowledge (MK) – 25 questions in 24 minutes
- Verbal Expression (VE)= (WK)+(PC)

  - Word Knowledge (WK) – 35 questions in 11 minutes
  - Paragraph Comprehension (PC) – 11 questions in 22 minutes

and

> The formula for computing an AFQT score is: AR + MK + (2 x VE).

That sounds a bit like SAT... and a quick search found [one paper](https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/81482/1/wp965.pdf) that talks of "cognitive skills as measured by the AFQT". (SAT is [pretty well correlated](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/the-perfect-score-project/201107/is-the-sat-iq-test) with IQ.) So, to what extent does AFQT correlate to more traditional IQ [sub-]scores?

Answer (score 3):

An answer is found in [an official memo, albeit from 1980](https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/monographs/MG265/images/webG1471.pdf), where

- the correlation of AFQT with WAIS (no version specified) was stated as 0.8 based on a Army "fact sheet" from 1965; the details of the comparative test could not be found
- an Air Force comparison found (in 1974) that the correlation (again with WAIS, no version specified) for white enlistees was (again) 0.8 but 0.77 for black enlistees.

(This ~0.8 is actually about the same as the correlation of IQ tests with SAT.) I don't know if the AFQT is still the same as back then.

A official-looking 2006 [concordance/translation table of AFQT score with SAT scores](http://www.nrcs.k12.oh.us/Downloads/ASVAB%20CONCORDANCE%20TABLES.pdf) can also be found, although it's rather summary; it doesn't mention a correlation coefficient.

Comment: It is worth noting that the most commonly used IQ tests don't even correlate perfectly *with themselves*. Or said in another way, of course there is always some measurement error. A good IQ test may have test-retest correlation of $r = 0.9$, and hence the correlation of $0.8$ is actually an underestimation of the strength of the relation between IQ tests and the AFQT, because some of that remaining $1-0.8 = 0.2$ is simply measurement noise.